# How to change datetime to specific time

Tags: php, datetime

I have problem changing time in specific given timedate. example:

timelimit is given 10:30:00

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if(date("Hi") < $timelimit)// CHECKS IF TIME IS RIGHT TO USE SCRIPT
{

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');// HERE I NEED TO CHANGE H:i:s to timelimit value
    
}
else
{
                                
}
```

i didnt find any solution how to make it

Comment: What't the problem you are facing? What have you tried to resolve it? What do you mean by "timelimit value"? `$timelimit` isn't defined in your code

Answer (score 1):

`date()` just returns a string, which you can use like any other.

If you want the current date, followed by a particular time, just concatenate those two strings together: `date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $someStringWithATimeIn;`

Note that if `$timelimit` is the string `'10:30:00'`, then `date("Hi") < $timelimit` won't work. Probably you want to compare them as timestamps (numbers representing a time) instead: `time() < strtotime('today ' . $timelimit);`

To avoid all these magic strings and numbers, you could work with [DateTimeImmutable objects](https://php.net/DateTimeImmutable) instead.